# Refresh bindings on activated window using MVVM-Light

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm-light

I have a main page that Loading Related Entity .

```
  private ICollectionView _notes;
    public ICollectionView Notes
    {
        get { return _notes; }
        set
        {
            _notes = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Notes");
        }
    }
        . 
        .
     Notes = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(db.Notes.Include(c => c.Category).ToList());
```

I navigate to sub-page category that change categories.

```
 private ICollectionView _categorie;
    public ICollectionView Categories
    {
        get { return _categorie; }
        set
        {
            if (_categorie == value)
                return;
            ICollectionView oldvalue = _categorie;
            _categorie = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Categories",oldvalue,value,true);
        }
    }



    Categories = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(db.Categories.ToList());
```

when user close the sub-page and back in mainpage, main page doesn't change.

How do I send a message or otherwise trigger a refresh of the bindings on that page?

Comment: have you inherit your mainpage class with INotifypropertychanged..

Comment: I use Mvvm Light, and mainpage inherit ViewModelBase.